Plotly line series animation: draw line continously instead of in steps?
I'm trying to produce an animated chart that will draw a couple of time-based line series smoothly over time.
I've managed to animate the line series using graph_objects. However, instead of having the lines being smoothly drawn from point to point by interpolating the gaps between frames, they're just drawn abruptly frame by frame (providing a link as this bug prevents me from uploading the gif here):
https://i.postimg.cc/hP6bW8y4/animation.gif
I've played around with the transition settings, but that only seems to affect how the line shape is smoothed out AFTER the new point is drawn.
Is there any way to have the line be continously drawn from point to point instead of jumping from one step to the next?
Here's my code:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
dates = [
    "2020-01-01",
    "2020-06-01",
    "2020-10-01",
    "2021-03-01",
    "2021-07-01",
    "2021-10-01",
    "2021-11-01",
]
series1 = [1477.60, 1474.45, 1448.40, 1447.40, 1444.40, 1449.40, 1441.40]
series2 = [1577.60, 1564.45, 1568.40, 1537.40, 1584.40, 1529.40, 1571.40]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(zip(dates, series1, series2)),
    columns=["date", "series_1", "series_2"],
)

# Base plot
fig = go.Figure(
    layout=go.Layout(
        updatemenus=[
            dict(type="buttons", direction="right", x=0.9, y=1.16),
        ],
        xaxis=dict(
            range=["2020-01-01", "2021-12-01"],
            autorange=False,
            tickwidth=2,
            title_text="Time",
        ),
        yaxis=dict(range=[1400, 1600], autorange=False, title_text="Values"),
        title="Test chart",
    )
)

# Add traces
init = 1

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.date[:init],
        y=df.series_1[:init],
        name="Series 1",
        visible=True,
        mode="lines",
        line_shape="spline",
        line=dict(color="#33CFA5"),
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.date[:init],
        y=df.series_2[:init],
        name="Series 2",
        visible=True,
        mode="lines",
        line_shape="spline",
        line=dict(color="#bf00ff"),
    )
)

# Animation
fig.update(
    frames=[
        go.Frame(
            data=[
                go.Scatter(x=df.date[:k], y=df.series_1[:k]),
                go.Scatter(x=df.date[:k], y=df.series_2[:k]),
            ]
        )
        for k in range(init, len(df) + 1)
    ]
)

# Extra Formatting
fig.update_xaxes(ticks="outside", tickwidth=2, tickcolor="white", ticklen=10)
fig.update_yaxes(ticks="outside", tickwidth=2, tickcolor="white", ticklen=1)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat=",")
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(x=0, y=1.1), legend_orientation="h")

# Buttons
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list(
                [
                    dict(
                        label="Play",
                        method="animate",
                        args=[
                            None,
                            {
                                "frame": {"duration": 1000},
                                "transition": {"duration": 1000},
                                "fromcurrent": True,
                            },
                        ],
                    ),
                ]
            )
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()

